# Paypal Return URL needed when using react-paypal + onApprove()?

Tags: reactjs, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

In my PayPal Sandbox App it asks for a return url:

[image]

Right now I am using the `onApprove` function in the `@paypal/react-paypal-js` package & do a router push if it's called. Do I still need to set this parameter on the paypal backend? Is there a difference?

I also do not understand what it currently says:

> nativexo://paypalpay

? What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

Return URLs in the app settings are used by Log in with PayPal and the native SDK. They are not used by normal PayPal Checkouts, even those which do redirect for approval and thus use a return URL specified when the order is set up. PayPal JS SDK checkouts do not redirect nor have a return URL anyway.